# Reroute bannerinstruction while offroutelistener detected

Tags: android, navigation, mapbox

I am overriding allowreroutefrom() function from routelistener to pick up my custom route when offroutelistener is detected. I am returning false and starting the new navigation with custom computed route. But I want to show the Rerouting bannerinstruction when reroute happens. How to give our own instruction in banner?

Answer (score 0):

The `InstructionView` has `showRerouteState()` and `hideRerouteState()` methods that you can use:

```
@Override
public boolean allowRerouteFrom(Point offRoutePoint) {

  // Fetch new route 

  InstructionView instructionView = findViewById(R.id.instructionView);
  instructionView.showRerouteState();

  return false;
}
```